# ImageMagick remove profiles

Tags: imagemagick, profile

I'm trying to remove all profile from jpg except exif. According to docs it could be don with regular expression (example for xmp). So I'm trying something similar

convert  in.jpg +profile '!exif,*' -size 570x375  -resize  570x375 -quality 65 out.jpg

but when I do verify -verbose I still see all profiles

My IM version: ImageMagick 6.5.9-0 2010-02-12 Q16 
Os : CentOS release 5.5 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with ImageMagick 6.6.2-6:

```
convert +profile '!exif,*' -size 570x375 -resize 570x375 -quality 65 in.jpg out.jpg
```

Have you tried to use the in-file argument as second last, not first?